# How Siddhi application in WSO2 SP handles an incoming data stream during redeployment?

Tags: wso2, siddhi, wso2-streaming-integrator

The topic is too big for me and I'm struggling with identifying a clear question. And I cannot find something in WSO2 Stream Processor documentation.

I've got a deployment of WSO2 SP on one machine. No Kafka integration, only enabled database persistence. The sources in Siddhi application are of HTTP type, so there is another service which sends events to its endpoint. During redeployment of Siddhi application, obviously, it becomes unavailable, but the external service still sending events. How does WSO2SP/Siddhi app avoid loosing of events which are coming regardless to its state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation and capturing metrics, it seems that during the deployment Siddhi application really became unavailable. The test is done on a single node deployment, not Minimum HA. So that the feeding services suppose to have re-try logic on sending events.